# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS keeps freezing

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, freeze

I have Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows 10. My PC Specifications are:

Processor: Intel Core i5 4690 3.5 GHz with Turbo boost upto 3.9 GHz

Ram: Corsair Vengeance DDR3 8GB clocked at 1600 MHz

Motherboard: Gigabyte B-85M D3H

Graphics Card: Zotac GTX 660 Synergy Edition 2GB

HDD: Western Digital 1TB Caviar Green WD10EZRX

PSU: Corsair VS650

Ubuntu works fine when I run pre-installed applications like Firefox, Libre Office or when I work on the terminal, but when I install and launch some third party apps from "Ubuntu Software", like Spotify, Stellarium, Chromium etc, my system gets completely frozen like mouse and keyboard not working and the only option I have is to restart my pc or trying "ALT" + "Print Screen" + "REISUB". What is wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: I suggest narrowing down the symptoms of the freeze.  E.g. when a freeze occurs, is it the windowing system?  To check that try Ctrl+Alt+F4.  If that gives you a console, log in and look for system errors at the end of the `journalctl -b0` output.